# Chart.js responsive option - Chart not filling container

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tL0voavj/). What am I doing wrong? Isn't the responsive option supposed to force the chart to fill it's container?

[image: Chart.js - Chart not filling container]

```
<div style="width:800px; height:400px;">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>


<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {

  var data = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
          {
              label: "My First dataset",
              fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
              pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
          },
          {
              label: "My Second dataset",
              fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
              pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
          }
      ]
  };
  options = {
    responsive: true
  };
  // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
  var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
  // This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
  var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry about this, but I realized that the version I was using was outdated. For future reference, I found an up to date version of chart.js [here](http://www.jsdelivr.com/).

```
//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chart.js/1.0.1-beta.4/Chart.min.js
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tL0voavj/158/) is the updated fiddle

Comment: maintainAspectRatio: false, inside your options might help that