# Getting chart.js to fill the vertical space

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, chart.js2

I have founds [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026204/getting-chart-js-bar-chart-to-fill-window) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334757/chart-js-responsive-option-chart-not-filling-container) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847582/chart-js-canvas-resize) for ways to get [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) plots to fill the **horizontal** space (using option `responsive = true`), but they only offer one of two behaviours for the vertical space:

- Either `maintainAspectRatio` is `true` and the vertical size adjusts automatically to preserve the aspect ratio when the width changes.
- Or `maintainAspectRatio` is `false` and the vertical size is fixed.

Is there a way to create plots that will fill the available **vertical** space?

I know I can use a `flex` layout to create a `div` that will fill the vertical space, so I tried to use that for my charts either directly:

```html
<div syle="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
   <div id="header">Foo</div>
   <canvas id="plot" style="flex-grow: 1"></canvas>
</div>
```

or by wrapping the `canvas` in a `flex` `div`:

```html
<div syle="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
   <div id="header">Foo</div>
   <div style="flex-grow: 1">
      <canvas id="plot"></canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```

always with `responsive = true`, but the plot never fills the vertical space.

Comment: I have this same question. Did you manage to find a workaround?

Comment: @JPM Not really, I wound up using a fixed aspect ratio and letting the width adjust automatically.